# VS 2012 project references all missing-- troubleshooting techniques?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, assemblies, nuget

I've downloaded a straightforward VS 2012 [solution](https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal) and for some reason am having trouble with the references in it-- they're all marked with yellow exclamation points, even core .Net libraries.

This isn't a problem in any of my other VS 2012 projects.  I've scrubbed and redownloaded the solution several times, each with the same result.

I'm using VS 2012 Professional, update 3, and I have the .Net 4.5 runtime installed.  So I think I'm caught up on the latest platform and tools.

I updated all the NuGet packages in the solution but that didn't help.  Would anyone know what I can look at to see where the problem is?  (I downloaded this same solution on another box and have no problems whatsoever.  Both machines are running Windows 7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popped open the Solution and got the following errors:

```
Warning 2   The command ""C:\****************\Downloads\PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal-master\PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal-master\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\*************\PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal-master\PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal-master\SPAJumpStart\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -o "C:***************\PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal-master\PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal-master\packages"" exited with code 1.  SPAJumpStart

Warning 1   Package restore is disabled by default. To give consent, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on Package Manager node and check 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.' You can also give consent by setting the environment variable 'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' to 'true'.   SPAJumpStart
```

Looks like the references are tied into a custom nuget package, including the normal .net 4.5 references. Enabling the 'EnableNuGetPackageRestore' option should fix the issue.

Comment: I'll look at that option, thanks.  In the Library Package Manager a dialog said the same thing as your message above, regarding package restore, so I said 'yes' and updated, with no difference.  With luck your way will tip the scales for me.